# How to make gcc print out the exact paths of the shared libraries needed by the executable

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I was hoping to create an automated tool that copies the needed shared libraries for any C program to a directory, so one can ship directly to end-users.

For example, I have a C program that uses openssl. Subsequently, it needs the following shared libraries to execute.

```
$ gcc test.c -lssl -lcrypto
$ readelf -d a.out

Dynamic section at offset 0x2dd8 contains 28 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libssl.so.1.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcrypto.so.1.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x1000
 0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x11b4
 ...
```

How can I make `gcc` output the exact path of the `.so`-files, so that I can copy them to a local directory and bundle into a zipfile?

(I'm planning to use the `-rpath` switch, to add that local directory to runtime library search path)

Comment: Why `gcc`? `ldd` does the job perfectly.

Comment: You have some basic problem with your environment setup if your `a.out` cannot find `libssl.so, etc...` Do you have the libraries installed in some non-standard place? As @user58697 says, `ldd a.out` is what you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can use dynamic injection. (On linux)You modify the environment variables as below

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/of/your/shared/library
export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="name/of/library"
export DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1 //by default
```

You can create the .sh script to run on run time like below

```
#!/bin/sh
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/of/your/shared/library
export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="name/of/library"
export DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1 //by default
$@
```